# android wear programmatically bring up app laucher

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

My Ticwatch E has a single physical button on the left side.
I find it very awkward to get to when I'm wearing a long shirt on.
Extending your arm to expose the watch face & touch/swipe is much easier.
So, I'm trying to add the equivalent of the "physical button press" action to my watchface.
These lines of code bring up a selection of apps but, the list is very limited.

```
                Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                if (startMain.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivity(startMain);
                }
```

I'd really like to bring up the native app launcher that's presented when the physical button is pressed.
Logcat reports this activity info when I press the physical button.

```
      I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.google.android.wearable.app/com.google.android.clockwork.home2.activity.HomeActivity2 (has extras)} from uid 1000 on display 0
```

Any ideas?
Oh, and gestures don't work. On the Ticwatch, gestures only allow you to flip between cards. The up/down write motion that (apparently) used to bring up the app launcher doesn't work.